# How to redirect part of the link in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to redirect part of the link in wordpress?
is there any plugin to do that?
for example: 
redirectiong : 
https://sajiran.com/product/ma25
to: 
https://sajiran.com/new-address/ma25

for all links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your .htaccess add the following:

```
Redirect 301 /product /new-address
```

This will redirect any link that starts with product to new-address

Comment: This method is also SEO friendly. Norouz Mobarak.